# Is the output of scapy.sprintf a raw string?why the length is wrong?

Tags: python, scapy

I want to analyze TCP packets by scapy. And I use pkt.sprintf('%Raw.load%') to extract tcp data. But the output string has something wrong with length. but the '\' is  deemed to be a str instead of a Escaped character.so '\x11' is considered as 4 different strings instead of a ASCII character.

Here are my codes:

```
from scapy.all import *
def findTCPdata(pkt):
    raw = pkt.sprintf("%Raw.load%")
    print raw
    print 'length of TCP data: '+ str(len(raw))
def main():
    pkts = rdpcap('XXX.pcap')
    for pkt in pkts:
        findTCPdata(pkt)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cAsp.jpg)

The length of each tcp data should be 17 instead of the value in screen(53,52,46,52).
4 tcp data are:

```
'U\x11\x04\x92\x02\x03\x1e\x03@\x03\xf8q=e\xcb\x15\r'
'U\x11\x04\x92\x02\x03.\x03@\x03\xf8q=e\xcb\xb8\x05'
'U\x11\x04\x92\x02\x03X\x03@\x03\xf8q=e\xcbiO'
'U\x11\x04\x92\x02\x03n\x03@\x03\xf8q=e\xcb\xdb\xe3'
```

Please help me solve the problem.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i see. i need a function to transform rawstring to string.
so i add codes after line 3(raw = pkt.sprintf("%Raw.load%")) like:

```
raw = raw.replace('\'','')
string = raw.decode('string_escape')
```

then the output is right